# select all element besides nth-child() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Could not find this anywhere

Say I have 5 divs like so

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

my jquery selector

```
$('.wrapper div:nth-child(3)')
```

This is great but how do I select all the divs besides nth-child(3)? 
I know I can combine two filters as follow:

```
$('.wrapper div:gt(3)')
$('.wrapper div:lt(3)')
```

and I tried chainning `:nth-child():not()` it returns the nth-child

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Do you truly want all descendants that are not the third child of their direct parent, or do you only want direct children of `.wrapper` that are not the third child of `.wrapper`?

Comment: the latter, sorry for the confusion. To be specific I need 
$('.wrapper div:nth-child(1)'), $('.wrapper div:nth-child(2)'), $('.wrapper div:nth-child(4)') and $('.wrapper div:nth-child(5)')

Comment: My point was that these selectors will also return descendants, such as div id `d1` from `<div class="wrapper"><div class="wrapper2"><div id="d1"></div></div></div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$('.wrapper > div:not(:nth-child(3))')
```

The `>` is necessary if you actually want only the direct children and not all matching `div` descendants that are not the third child of their immediate parent element.